# How to run CitNetExplorer.jnlp using javaws on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: java-web-start

On my ubuntu 18.04.01 I try to type:

$ javaws CitNetExplorer.jnlp

```
selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
WARNING: package javax.jnlp not in java.desktop
Unable to use Firefox's proxy settings. Using "DIRECT" as proxy type.
This application does not specify a Codebase in its manifest. Please verify with the applet's vendor. Continuing. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/no_redeploy.html for details.
This application does not specify a Codebase in its manifest. Please verify with the applet's vendor. Continuing. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/no_redeploy.html for details.
Starting application [nl.citnetexplorer.app.CitNetExplorer] ...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceColorUtilities.getDefaultBackgroundColor(SubstanceColorUtilities.java:758)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceColorUtilities.getBackgroundFillColor(SubstanceColorUtilities.java:661)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.__org__pushingpixels__substance__internal__ui__SubstancePanelUI__installDefaults(SubstancePanelUI.java:73)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.installDefaults(SubstancePanelUI.java)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:62)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.__org__pushingpixels__substance__internal__ui__SubstancePanelUI__installUI(SubstancePanelUI.java)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.ui.SubstancePanelUI.installUI(SubstancePanelUI.java)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:685)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:150)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.createGlassPane(JRootPane.java:521)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:348)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:279)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
    at nl.citnetexplorer.app.CitNetExplorer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at nl.citnetexplorer.app.CitNetExplorer$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

```
$ javaws --version
selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
WARNING: package javax.jnlp not in java.desktop
icedtea-web 1.8 (1.8)
```

It should run the app but failed. How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Warmest Regards,
Suryadi